# MVC: un controller y view por formulario?

Tags: php, mvc

desde mi index.php llamo a distintas opciones usando mvc.

Por ejemplo clientes: lista los clientes con listarcliente.php. Pero ahi tengo editar y nuevo cliente.

La pregunta es: tengo que crear un clientecontroller.php y un vistaagregar.php y vistaeditar.php, con su modulo..

Y lo mismo para articulos, nuevoticket, etc?

Programo desde cero sin ningun framework

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas una vista por cada formulario, pero puedes hacerlas aparte e irlas incluyendo mientras la accion llame al controlador correspondiente

Comment: Y si en muchos casos se necesitan paginas dinamicas, pero si tendria que hacer un controlador por cada logica digamos..

Comment: @user3780282 bueno, tu puedes tener varios formularios como vistas, y los controladores a parte. Son independientes. Sin embargo, deberian tener una logica entre ellos